# How do I test Flex App on iOS device(IPAD) without Registration to Developer Program?

Tags: ios, apache-flex

Is there any way I can test my Flex application on Ipad device without registration to developer program?
I have heard that there are some converters, that converts .swf to app for mac. Is there some tools for iOS?

Device is jailbroken.

Comment: Doesn't flashbuilder put out a .ipa file? I haven't worked with it for iOS at all, but I thought it would.

Comment: It does i think. But it asks for certificates to do that.

Comment: I believe it allows you to create your own certificate?

Comment: Are you sure? Where exactly ?

Comment: google 'shared apple certificate'

Answer (score 3):

You can't create IPA without certificate. The only one way - find shared apple certificate (as i did). After that you will be able to convert and test on your device.
But be aware that non-jailbroken devices would not be able to install you application. So, if you rely to sell you product or install on other device the only one way - buy apple cert.

Answer (score 2):

Check here: [Adobe Air apps for ios](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-ios.html)

even if you have an jailbroken iPad, you can`t put your own apps inside. All of the need to be previously signed by a developer. The easiest way is to ask for a friend...

Answer (score 2):

`"Is there any way I can test my Flex application on Ipad device without registration to developer program?"`

No. iPhone is just like that - thank Steve Jobs.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS064a3073e805330f6c6abf312e7545f65e-8000.html#WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-27e02e9a12ee20e4a60-7fff

If you know an iPhone developer, you'll have to borrow his. Or pay the $100/year.